# Getting database information from SQL Project in C# Project

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I'm working in Visual Studio 2013 in one Solution (`MySolution`).

From OOP perspective I separate C# code in domain layer in one Project (`MyCProject`) from the main database who is placed in specific SQL Server Database Project (`MySQLProject`).

Both projects shared same namespace, are stored in the same `MySolution` solution.

**How can I access the tables data in `MySQLProject` in `MyCProject`?**

The tables are stored inside the `MySQLProject` project, but not in SQL Server Express database server who is also installed on the machine, does that affect the accessibility?

At the end, maybe I have not mentioned some relevant information, so if someone can help me I would be very happy if the answer can be little bit detailed like a walk through information sheet. Because I don't know what information is relevant to write so the problem can be resolved in best way as possible.

Comment: Are you using an ORM tool (e.g. EntityFramework) to map your SQL tables to C# entities?

Comment: Well I just have set up these two projects, so no I haven't use EntityFramework. What do you reccomend for simple solution? Is EF maybe the only tool that is relevant in this chase - or does simplier solutions exist?

Comment: Could you add an example of the classes in your MySqlProject? and what do you mean with _The tables are stored inside the MySQLProject project, but not in SQL Server Express database server_ If you want to store anything you need these tables in Sql Server Express.

Comment: There are a large number of ORM tools available in c# so there is no point in recommending one without knowing anything about the requirements of your project. Here is a list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET. Entity Framework is included in the .NET framework  from 3.5 SP1 onwards and would have lots of support materials so it might not be a bad starting point

Comment: In MySQLProject I have create a tables with .sql endings. And also there is a file with .refactoring ending.

What I mean with SQL Express, I mean that the table (with the .sql endings) are not stored in the SQL Server Express server, the table are just stored in SQL Database Project. So the tables are not part of a database in the SQL Express Server.

Should I do ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the C# Project and access the tables there?

Comment: @Sandri its not clear why you needed to split into 2 projects. If your looking for separation of concern then use design patterns for that.EF or ADO.net are only tools to access the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store data, then you need to "Publish" the `MySQLProject` database project via the "BUILD" menu. Data is stored in a database, not in a Visual Studio project. You are going to have to publish this to your SQL Server Express DB in order to test any of the app functionality.

---

FYI, since there seems to be some confusion, based on the comments on the question, as to the purpose of Database projects, I will say:

- Database projects are not for DB access, they are for defining DB objects.
- If the goal of creating a Database project was to be able to define Tables and Stored Procedures, etc and be able to publish them easily and validate them, etc, then this is an appropriate usage.
- If the goal of creating the Database project was having separation of a Data Access Layer, then that is *not* going to work. Database projects do not facilitate access to the data. There are several different ways to access data (Entity Framework / DataAdapters / SqlCommand + SqlDataReader), and none of them require a separate project.

Comment: Hello srutzky - thanks a lot for the answer.
You are telling me to "Add Database Reference" - but in MyCProject it's not possible. But in the MySQLProject it's possible to add database reference.

What should I do then, should I use EntityFramework or ADO.NET?

Comment: @Sandri I must have been using a Database Project earlier. I see now that non-Database projects don't have the "Add Database Reference" option. I have updated my answer to remove that info. So, what are you trying to do? Are you wanting to model your database or create a data access layer?

Comment: Yes I'm creating data access layer more or less - what is better approach to do that?

Comment: @Sandri That is a matter of preference. A lot of people seem to like Entity Framework as it handles most (sometimes all) of the SQL for you. I am primarily a database developer so I prefer regular ADO.NET SqlCommand / SqlDataReader as I write my own SQL and use stored procedures.